# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')

Tags: android-studio, configuration, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I just started mobile automation testing and I'm trying to write tests for android on Android Studio with Appium, however I think I just did something wrong in configuration process. I was getting some other errors and these are the things I've done so far.

- set ANDROID_HOME path
- set JAVA_HOME path
- updated node version

After doing these I've started appium server and tried again. I was able to communicate with the emulator but something is still off.

[run command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw4fo.png)

appium-doctor and flutter doctor seems fine though.

[appium-doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUNR1.png)

[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxOiJ.png)

And this is the exact error message I get.

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUB9h.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the case a while ago, thought could help someone. The problem was the first config I copied from another how-to source. It was trying to use appium-flutter-driver and I assume therefore there was a code snippet like this:

```
'appium:automationName': 'Flutter'
```

Which wasn't working because I was trying to run it with appium-flutter-finder. I don't exactly know what happened there but when I looket it up from appium's guide and did the default config they gave there the problem is gone. Which is:

```
 'appium:automationName': 'Appium'
```